# laravel condition add amount nested

Tags: php, laravel

Code: I have a condition on this, but it's not clear for me

```
$check_account1 = false;
$check_account2 = false;
$user1_amount = 100;
$user2_amount = 100;

if ($account->type == "A") {
    $check_account1 = true;
    $amount = 100;
    if ($check_account1) {
        $amount = $user1_amount;
    } else {
        $amount += $user1_amount;
    }
} elseif ($account->type == "B") {
    $amount = $user2_amount;
}

$insert = new Amount;
$insert->user_id = $account->id;
$insert->amount = $amount;
$insert->save();
```

---

**EDIT**: I have a users which has a rank of `Basic, Junior, Premium, Advanced, Senior`, which is every user has it's corresponding amount based on their `rank`.
If someone is not present or not available, the amount based on his rank will go to the `rank` next to him, if the user is present he will receive the amount based on his `rank`. So if `Basic, Junior, Premium and Advanced` is not present, the sum of their corresponding amount will go to `Senior`

Present meaning it's in the `database table`, if the loop doesn't get a user with that `rank`, I call it absent.

This is how it goes:

```
Basic - 10
Junior - 20
Premium - 30
Advanced - 40
Senior - 50

  $amount_to_transfer = 0;
  $amount_to_receive = 0;
  foreach($users as $user){
    if($user->rank == 'Basic'){
      // basic is present, add 10 to himself, if not 10 will go to the next rank which is Junior
      $amount->amount = 10;
      $amount->save();
    }
    else{
      //
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to put the logic in a loop and go through all users that are stored in a collection/array?

Comment: yes @lyyka exactly

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to loop through your users, and transfer amount from those that are not present to the first next user that is present, here is the code that should accomplish that task:

```php
  $amount_to_transfer = 0;
  $amount_to_receive = 100;
  foreach($users as $user){
    if($user->present){
      $user->amount += $amount_to_receive + $amount_to_transfer;
      $amount_to_transfer = 0;
      // If you want to save the user here
      // $user->save();
    }
    else{
      $amount_to_transfer += $amount_to_receive;
    }
  }
```

I assumed that your user model has `present` property which tells if the user is present or not (boolean value) and that the amount is stored in `amount` field. You can adapt this condition based on your properties in your User model.

All in all, you just need to define a transfer amount, which starts off as zero and add it alongside with receiving amount every time the user is present. If user is not present, just increment the amount to transfer so it can be added to first next present user.

### Adapted

Here is the adapted code, I used dummy collections and ranks. Please adapt this to your settings. In this example there is no Advanced rank, so senior will get 50 + 40 amount.

```php
  $ranks = collect([
    (object) ['name' => 'Basic', 'amount' => 10],
    (object) ['name' => 'Junior',  'amount' => 20],
    (object) ['name' => 'Premium',  'amount' => 30],
    (object) ['name' => 'Advanced',  'amount' => 40],
    (object) ['name' => 'Senior',  'amount' => 50],
  ]);
  $users = collect([
    (object) ['rank' => 'Basic', 'amount' => 0],
    (object) ['rank' => 'Junior', 'amount' => 0],
    (object) ['rank' => 'Premium', 'amount' => 0],
    (object) ['rank' => 'Senior', 'amount' => 0],
    (object) ['rank' => 'Basic', 'amount' => 0],
  ]);
  $amount_to_transfer = 0;
  $available_ranks = $users->pluck('rank');
  foreach($ranks as $rank){
    if(!in_array($rank->name, $available_ranks->toArray()))
    {
      $amount_to_transfer += $rank->amount;
    }
    else{
      $usersOfThisRank = $users->filter(function($usr, $key) use($rank){
        return $usr->rank == $rank->name;
      });
      $usersOfThisRank->map(function($usr, $key) use($rank, $amount_to_transfer){
        $usr->amount += $rank->amount + $amount_to_transfer;
        // $usr->save();
      });
      $amount_to_transfer = 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you lyyka, can we go deeper? because I have more conditions to add there. I will update the question with your code.

Comment: Yes, you can just append all your conditions in the first if, or even declare a function that will determine if the user is 'eligible' to receive the amount. Then you can just call that function and return true/false from it.

Comment: lykka, I updated my question so I can explain it more, sorry, I'm having trouble in english